# Help needed in transcription of music lyrics

Tags: lyrics

Again I'm stuck with some lyrics. I have difficulties listening to song lyrics in English.

[Spiral End (Worship)](https://worship2.bandcamp.com/track/spiral-end?from=search&search_item_id=3367395539&search_item_type=t&search_match_part=%3F&search_page_id=2378852082&search_page_no=0&search_rank=1&logged_in_menubar=true)
Apparently there isn't a source with transcript lyrics yet.

My poor tries to transcribe it read:

```
Hot teenage dreams
be hard to slide demons
like the french bridge back then was at a win
hot teenage dreams
are fragile eaqual

The ghost of the future
best impressive
united to bring us riffs
that black sence
shouldn't my justice

Bad to see
our teenage life
reveal that sound tonight
if I should dance tonight

Oh, oh, oh
sound of the spiral end
world of the dead
hey man <***>

We feel like changin' sound
of the spiral end
a world of the dead
hey man <***>

can't decide

oh, oh, oh
if I should dance tonight

Oh, oh, oh
sound of the spiral end
a world of the dead
hey man <***>

<repetitions>
```

Maybe I got 50% right, maybe less. That's a poor quota. Let alone my even worse understanding of the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hot teenage dreams
They haunt us like demons
Like the <***> back <***>
Hot teenage schemes
Our fragile ego

The ghosts of the future
<***>
United to bring us rain
Black glasses
Shoulder black dresses

Fantasies of teenage <***>
Reveal that sound tonight
If I should dance tonight

Oh, oh, oh
The sound of the spiral end
A world of the dead
Hey man <***>

Revealed by shapes and sounds
Of the spiral end
A world of the dead
Hey man <***>

Oh, oh, oh
I can't decide

Oh, oh, oh
If I should dance tonight

Oh, oh, oh
The sound of the spiral end
A world of the dead
Hey man <***>

Revealed by the shapes and sounds
Of the spiral end
A world of the dead
Hey man <***>

<repetitions>
```

I'm pretty confident in what I transcribed, but anything with <***> is something I couldn't discern confidently. For your purposes, I would slide in whatever you had transcribed for those; I wasn't 100% confident that you had those right, so I left them out.

I'm an American English speaker, so the accent of the singer (being that he's from Switzerland) is why I had trouble figuring out certain parts. Some of those parts may even be in another language, I'm not sure.

And since this artist is on Bandcamp, you could probably reach out fairly easily to get the lyrics directly from him. He might even get a kick out of what you and I came up with!

Comment: Yeah, now some phrases make much more sense. As far as song lyrics can make sense at all! Thanks for the effort.